# Write a java script for doing the following. 1. Create a Cookie and add these four user id’s and passwords to this Cookie

Tags: android

User Authentication:

Assume four users

`user1`, `user2`, `user3` and `user4`

having the passwords

`pwd1`, `pwd2`, `pwd3`, and `pwd4`

respectively. Write a java script for doing the following.

1. Create a Cookie and add these four user id’s and passwords to this Cookie.
2. Read the user id and passwords entered in the Login form (week1) and authenticate with the values (user id and passwords ) available in the cookies. If he is a valid user(i.e., user-name and password match) you should welcome him by name(user-name) else you should display “`You are not an authenticated user`“

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [homework assignment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: yaa but you tell me how to set 4 users id and passwords as cookies and how to retrive

Comment: We are not here to do your homework.Instead we are here to help you with the code you have written so far

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title> login Page </title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function setusercookies()
{
   var user1 ={};
   user1.user1 = "user1";
   user1.pwd1 = "user1123";
   jsonString=JSON.stringify(user1);
   document.cookie ="cookieObject="+jsonString;

   var user2 ={};
   user2.user2="user2";
   user2.pwd2="user2123";
   jsonString=JSON.stringify(user2);
   document.cookie ="cookieObject1="+jsonString;

   var user3 ={};
   user3.user3="user3";
   user3.pwd3="user3123";
   jsonString=JSON.stringify(user3);
   document.cookie ="cookieObject2="+jsonString;

   var user4 ={};
   user4.user4="user4";
   user4.pwd4="user4123";
   jsonString=JSON.stringify(user4);
   document.cookie ="cookieObject3="+jsonString; 
    alert("User id and password of four users are set as cookie successfully \n"+document.cookie);
  }
 function cleartextboxes()
{
    document.getElementById("usr").value="";
    document.getElementById("pwd").value="";

} 
function getCookie()
{
    var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
    var user=document.getElementById("usr").value;
    var pass=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        var namesplit=nameValueArray[j];
        for(var i=0;i<namesplit.length;i++)
        {
           var n=namesplit.indexOf(":");
           var cuser=namesplit.substring(namesplit.indexOf(":")+2,namesplit.indexOf(",")-1);
           var cpass=namesplit.substring(namesplit.indexOf(":",parseInt(n+1))+2,namesplit.indexOf(";")-2);
        }
        if(user==cuser)
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    if(user!="" && pass!="")
    {
        if(user==cuser && pass==cpass)
        {
            alert("Welcome "+cuser);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You are not a authorised person");
        }
    }
    else
        alert("Please enter required fields...");

}
</script>
</head> 
<body onload="setusercookies()"> 
<table border="1" size="50%">
    <tr>
       <td>User Name:</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="usr" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="pwd" /></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
           <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="cleartextboxes()"/>
           <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="getCookie()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: add user ids and passwords to the cookie using JSON.stringify() method and add string of each user to the cookie which is easy to get the values by using the string operations of javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn about [How to answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)